# Disable Button While processing Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I disable a a button while in processing? I have made a like button, but it takes some delay to register the like on db. How can I prevent the button press while processing is done. ??

```
onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _color = Colors.green;
                    _icon = Icon(Icons.favorite);
                    final like = LikeData(
                      campaingID: donation.campaignID,
                      dateTime: Timestamp.now(),
                      userName: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.displayName,
                      userId: user.uid,
                    );
                    likeService.newLike(donation, like);
```

how can i prevent double tap on this button event??

Comment: if the answer solved your question , accept it mark it as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
bool isProcessing = false; // in your class before build method

onPressed: !isProcessing ? () {
          setState(() {
            isProcessing = true;
            _color = Colors.green;
            _icon = Icon(Icons.favorite);
            final like = LikeData(
              campaingID: donation.campaignID,
              dateTime: Timestamp.now(),
              userName: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.displayName,
              userId: user.uid,
            );
            likeService.newLike(donation, like).then((val) {
              setState() {
                isProcessing = false;
              }
            });
          });
        } : null,
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as three different states, e.g. "initial", "pressedConfirmationPending" and "pressedAndConfirmed". The button can then be enabled depending on this status, e.g.:

```
String buttonStatus = 'initial';
...
MyButton(
  ...
  enabled: buttonStatus == 'initial' || buttonStatus == 'pressedAndConfirmed',
  ...
);
```

Set the status to 'pressedConfirmationPending' just before you start the input processing, and then to 'pressedAndConfirmed' after your receive confirmation that processing is finished.

Also, the button's design and child widget will most likely be different, and possibly also it's onPressed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do adding a variable between processing.

I think that 'newLike' is synchronous method.
So you set checking variable true and processing 'newLike'.
After that set checking variable false to enable button.

```
bool isProcessing = false;

...

onPressed: isProcessing ? null : () async {
                  setState(() {
                     isProcessing = true;

                    final like = LikeData(
                      campaingID: donation.campaignID,
                      dateTime: Timestamp.now(),
                      userName: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.displayName,
                      userId: user.uid,
                    );
                    await likeService.newLike(donation, like);
                  });

                  setState(() {
                    _color = Colors.green;
                    _icon = Icon(Icons.favorite);
                      isProcessing = false;
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to create bool variable like this
'

bool _isworking=false;

onPressed:(){

if(_isworking==false){

```
 setState(() {
_isworking=true;
});
```

{{  here your function }}

setState(() {

_isworking=false;

});

}
else
{

print('the Function is working now please wait ');

//you can edit this and show the user a dialog that the process is going on and he need to wait

}

}